# Detecting an Application Focus Change / Hooking something for HWND changes?

Tags: c#, focus, hwnd

How could I detect when any application loses focus?  Is there any system hooks to use?  I want to pick up when ever a new application is in focus, or when one is lost.  Even having the "current" HWND of the user would be good.

I am using C#, however, its all win api stuff I am sure... so any info would be great.

Comment: Update

I know I can use GetForegroundWindow() to get the current window HWND, I just want to subscribe to an event that will notify me of it changing.

Answer (score 5):

Use `SetWindowsHookEx` to set either a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` or `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` global hook, and look for `WM_SETFOCUS` and or `WM_KILLFOCUS` messages.